# Python GIL: Do all participants in an expression have ref count incremented for the duration of the expression?

Tags: python, gil

Let's say I have a simple C++ class:

```
class Widget
{
public:
    Widget() :
            x(1)
    { }

    void sleep()
    {
        sleep(x);
    }

private:
    int x;
};
```

`Widget::sleep` blocks, so I would like to free up the GIL so that Python can do some other stuff, so I wrapped `Widget::sleep` in a function like this:

```
static void pyWidgetSleep(Widget& self)
{
    PyThreadState* state = PyEval_SaveThread();
    self.sleep();
    PyEval_RestoreThread(state);
}
```

For completeness, the binding code looks like this:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libnative)
{
    boost::python::class_<Widget>("Widget")
        .def("sleep", &pyWidgetSleep);
}
```

I have a simple Python script that looks like this:

```
import libnative
import threading

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = libnative.Widget()
        self.sleeping = False

    def foo(self):
        self.sleeping = True
        self.x.sleep()

c = C()
t = threading.Thread(target=c.foo)
t.start()
while not c.sleeping:
    pass
del c.x
```

Do all participants in an expression get their ref count incremented for the duration of the expression?
The only referant to `c.x` when used in `C.foo` is `c`, which the line after `t.start()` conveniently deletes.
Since `pyWidgetSleep` releases the GIL, `del c.x` might decrement the last reference to the `Widget` instance, causing undefined behavior.

---

I can't make this break on my machine, which seems to be a good indication that it works as I would expect, but reference-counting isn't documented to this degree of clarity
(or, at the very least, I can't seem to find it). The relevant portion of CPython appears to be `PyEval_EvalCodeEx`, which looks like it applies `Py_INCREF` to all arguments
involved in a function call, but I could be totally off on that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is *yes, it is safe*. This happens as a consequence of how member functions are called in Python. Consider if `Widget` was implemented in Python:

```
class Widget:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

    def sleep(self):
        os.sleep(self.x)
```

Notice how the first parameter to `Widget.sleep` is `self`? The reference count is incremented for the duration of the call! It seems obvious in retrospect...